# Flex: Why can't I get sub-children of display object?

Tags: apache-flex

I am having problems accessing sub-children of my displayObject. Here is my code:private

```
function resizeTag(event:MouseEvent):void{
            var currTagPos:Number = 1; 
            var theTagBox:DisplayObject = tagCanvas.getChildAt(currTagPos); //i have confirmed that it exists on the stage and has sub-children

            trace(theTagBox.getChildAt(0).width);
        }
```

Essentially I'm trying to get:

```
tagCanvas.getChildAt(currTagPos).getChildAt(0).width;
```

but it's not working. Thanks for any guidance you can provide :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I needed to call it as a DisplayObjectContainer. I did this instead:

```
trace((tagCanvas.getChildByName(currTagName) as Canvas).getChildAt(3) as Button);
```

I found this post which helped me figure it out:
http://www.nabble.com/undefined-method-getChildAt-td19812715.html